# Accepting null arguments for class instances in Typescript constructors

Tags: typescript

Typescript here. My `User` class:

```
class User {
  private name: string;
  private managerOf: User;

  constructor(name: string, managerOf: User) {
    this.name = name;
    this.managerOf = managerOf;
  }

  getName(): string {
    return this.name;
  }

  isManagerOf(user: User): boolean {
    return user.getName() == this.name;
  }

}

let jerry = new User("Jerry", null);
let jane = new User("Jane", jerry);
```

This produces the following error, when passing `null` into Jerry's ctor:

```
Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'
```

What can I do so that I can pass `null` in for Jerry's `managerOf` value?

[Full reproducible example is here.](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.9.3&sourceType=module&code=MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoa0AOSCWAbmAC4LQB2YAtggFzQTH7kDmA3JjvkadFWJRbIA8gDN68ZB07AA9uUZIArsGKykACko16ivKwA0fAWCFIxExCgA+FJSBABKNJyzEAFnggA6bWQC8FNQIHFhunj78giKi0IFRpjGh0AC+6JxCxABywRqOukz6LC5h0EgIxEpI5NAeXr7ByWmcXgCyJmZiGkpWlsj50ABGsrIgCAIlYeWV1dA9yN6ZOTR5cYF1Pn5N6c1jxNAAVshIAJ5xFAgA7nBWGgBEAFLHJ3dG5PZOHHuHAgEX15JNI9fq9Ds9HF8KmDyOQ8H9yFcbsh7k8YXDQQdfhD0t9+KdzgiAbc7u1TqD3g5sbiwEghATEYD7qShKC8ScqVC8QBrelE5Ekmlc1k0oTY9DfMAOQEQegAQSQSDAJwAPICAHznADaRwVJyMmIR+oQaIQRjZZpFpuMSC5AF1pAgAB7YdT7VBIpBGSUgaWpDhAA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGYBfEWg&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA)

Comment: constructor(name: string, managerOf: User | null)

Comment: but then I get `Type 'User | null' is not assignable to type 'User'.`

Comment: Then make `managerOf` nullable as well? I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that I've posted a succinct, reproducible code example and no one has (yet) shown me what is needed to make the code compile. How would I make `managerOf` nullable as well, and why would I need to do that if I specify it being nullable in the constructor.

Comment: private managerOf: User | null;

Comment: So its necessary **both** on the constructor and the field definition? Thats whack yo!

Comment: You have told TypeScript that managerOf is of type User. You need to also allow it to be null as shown above.

Comment: I'm just saying it should be one or the other, but not both. I should make it nullable at the constructor definition or the field definition but requiring it in both places is straight nonsense. Not critiquing you at all (thank you for your comments here!) but syntactically that is gibberish.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup - you can add the `private` keyword inside the constructor to remove the field definiton: https://tsplay.dev/w1A6Aw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So its necessary [to specificy null on] both on the constructor and the field definition?

Yes, but only because of how the `managerOf` it's declared. It all flows from the type of the property, and Typescript enforces that the rest must match.

---

You declared it:

```
private managerOf: User;
```

Which means only a `User` is a valid type to be assined to `managerOf`. `null` is not a `User` so is not allowed.

Now you go to the constructor:

```
class User {
  private name: string;
  private managerOf: User;

  constructor(name: string, managerOf: User) {
    this.name = name;
    this.managerOf = managerOf;
  }
}

new User('qwerty', null) // error
```

Here you can't pass in `null` because the constructor doesn't allow `null` there. So let's fix that:

```
class User {
  private name: string;
  private managerOf: User;

  constructor(name: string, managerOf: User | null) {
    this.name = name;
    this.managerOf = managerOf; // error
  }
}

new User('qwerty', null) // fine
```

Now you can pass `null` to the constructor, but `null` still isn't an allowed type for the `memberOf` property, so you get an error when you try to do that assignment.

So now let's allow the property to `null`:

```
class User {
  private name: string;
  private managerOf: User | null;

  constructor(name: string, managerOf: User | null) {
    this.name = name;
    this.managerOf = managerOf; // fine
  }
}

new User('qwerty', null) // fine
```

So, if the property `memberOf` is allowed to be `null` then that *needs* to part of the type.

And the `memberOf` constructor argument is totally separate from the `memberOf` property of the class instances. The only thing that links them is that you decide to assign one to the other, and Typescript enforces type safety in that assignment.

---

How's typescript supposed to know that you don't want to do something like this?

```
class User {
  private name: string,
  private managerOf: User

  constructor(name: string, managerOf: User | null) {
    this.name = name
    this.managerOf = managerOf || defaultManager
  }
}

const jerry = new User("Jerry", null);
jerry.managerOf.name // returns the default name
```

Here you accept `null` in the constructor, but the proeprty can't be `null` and is populated with a default value.

Cases like this are why you have to put it "both" places.

---

It's worth noting there is a common shorthand for this:

```
class User {
  constructor(
    private name: string,
    private managerOf: User | null
  ) {}
}

new User('qwerty', null) // fine
```

This syntax accepts a constructor argument and assigns it to an instance property only ever declaring it once.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoa1gHsB2EALkgK7CE5IAUmW0ADkgJYBuYhC0eYAtggFzQizPAHMANLSyNW7TjzDdRyAPIAzQfGTQAPlxIgQtAJRoAvulrLCAOV4IqxwcKZi0U6EgSESSPNEIACyYIADpuPgBuWgtaEIBZRTBlJHUqEkQkTUynaAAjHBwQBEV3Ok9vX38M5FDrOz5HaABeZoDgsIiEaKxY2OLCaAArZCQATxauBAB3OEyqACIAKVGxhfF9Q2NogeHFTja8GbnkRaX99eHV7fRdkbw8JgOp2a1qZYQHp8uh-Zvb7zQBTjSZHV7zBaJcaXPAGEA3XbA5Sg45vRZQ5SXYFjBGA4EAaxR4NOkLASHxWLJyn+uzAhjeEEEAEEkEgwGMADxvAB8kwA2iNWWMNr8jiLPo8EBtsdKqVKgWT8QBdaLoBAAD3olEGqBOSA2dJADOgZmiQA)